# Finding out related data from tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have three tables in my mysql database which looks like following:
[image]

## EDIT

The table "members" holds the name and code of some members . Now the table "Boss" contains the name of the member who has been selected as a Boss for an event. Each boss has at least one subordinate (please check the table subordinates).

Now what I am trying to do is find out the names and their points that Bon Jovi (pls check the table table:members) is associated with. When finding out there is a condition... if the "condition_type" from table:boss is 1 then the values from subordinates would be in the right side and if the "condition_type" from table:boss is 0 then the values from subordinates would be in the left side.

Now what I am trying to find out looks like following.

[image]

Comment: see you this post this will answer you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053670/how-to-inter-link-three-mysql-tables-using-codeigniter/10053734#10053734

Comment: Thanks Raheel, for your reply and for your answer in my another post. The thing is the script you showed me in that post.. joining those tables correctly but unfortunately its not helping me to achieve what I have mentioned here in this post. Could you please help me here. :)

Comment: Please make your question more clear

Comment: @raheel shan , thanks again for your reply. I have updated my answer, please kindly take a look at that. If you find anything unclear please let me know. I am trying hard to find out the solution but I can't. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK i have found a solution for you i am posting

```
$condition  = 1;// Condition will be provided by you for selection. Could be zero  
$data   =   array(
        'members.name',
        'subordinates.points',
        'subordinates.event'
);

$this->db->select($data);
$this->db->join('members','members.code = subordinates.member_code','left');
$this->db->join('boss','boss.event = subordinates.event','left');
$this->db->where('boss.condition_type',$condition);
$this->db->where('boss.event    =   subordinates.event');
$this->db->get('subordinates');
```

Also i have event in the selection so that you recognize the difference of events the query will bring. Kindly test and see if it works ok for you. There might be a little difference in the column names. A good approach is to use like this for easy and understandable relationship between tables.

```
Table1 :  members
Columns : id , code , name
Table2 :  boss
Columns : id , event , member_code , condition_type
Table3 :  subordinates
Columns : id , boss_event , member_code , points
```

Comment: I am very sorry for the late response. I couldn't check your script before because I somehow had lost all my databases. But today I re created the database and checked it and found that if I change the $condition= 1; to $condition= 0; only then it works.  Thanks again for your reply and time. :)

Comment: I think your waork has been simploified. You only have to provide the condition and that's all .